# how do i pass props to next screen using Navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

`<Navigate to={"/plans"} />;`
I am using this to navigate to plans page but i want to send some data with it any idea how can I do it? new to programming

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass data in route state on the `Navigate` component's `state` prop.

[Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate)

> ```
> declare function Navigate(props: NavigateProps): null;
>
> interface NavigateProps {
>   to: To;
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: State;
> }
> ```

Usage:

```
<Navigate to={"/plans"} state={{ data }} />
```

And to access the route state on the target routed component use the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation) hook access it.

```
const { state } = useLocation();

...

const { data } = state;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can read here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params. you can pass some props using navigate and route.

for example in screen 1

```
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
        }}
      />
```

in screen 2

```
function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params;
  return (
  );
}
```

you can navigate using the name of screen

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: OP appears to be using `react-router-dom`, not `react-navigation`. It's a completely different package.