# How to pass query params using Next js next/navigation router

Tags: javascript, next.js

So, I'm doing

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
const router = useRouter()
...
router.push('/foo?bar=10')
```

and it pushes only 'foo' into the url. How to pass query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i pass props to next screen using Navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621070/how-do-i-pass-props-to-next-screen-using-navigate)

Comment: no, it doesn't answer at all

Comment: I have the same issue here and it's very disappointing that there's not a doc for such an easy and common case.

Comment: Hi Auine, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @SherleyDev double check middleware if you have one
i18n example in the nextjs docs DOES remove query :)

Comment: It works. Thank you:)

Answer (score -1):

u might use `useSearchParams().get('Your Parameter name')`